# Does the Laplace transform of $f(t)=(1-H_{a} (t)) \exp{[(-1)^b (t-a)^2+(t-a)^{2021}]}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$, $a>b$. Does the Laplace transform of the following exist? $$f(t)=(1-H_{a} (t)) \exp{[(-1)^b (t-a)^2+(t-a)^{2021}]}$$

Should Ι distinguish the cases for $b$?

1. $b$ is odd
2. $b$ is even

Comment: What is $H_a(t)$?

Comment: $Η_a(t)=H(t-a)$, which $Η\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the Heavyside function.

Comment: Well, in this case your integral is not indefinite anyway?

Comment: I get it, thanks. Now I want to answer the question if the Laplace transform of $f(t)=H_{a} (t) \exp{[(-1)^b (t-a)^2+\sin (t-a)]}$ exist. The Laplace transform have the form $\int_a^\infty e^{-st} e^{[(-1)^b (t-a)^2+\sin (t-a)]} \ dt$. This is not just a finite integral right?

Comment: If $b$ is odd the integral clearly converges. If $b$ is even, then not. You may be able to define it by calculating it for continuous $b$ with $\Re(e^{i\pi b}) < 0$ and then continue the result analytically to $\Re(e^{i\pi b})>0$ if it exists.

Comment: thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L} (f(t)) = \int_0^a e^{(-1)^b (t - a)^2 + (t - a)^{2021}} \cdot e^{-st} \: dt$$
This is an integral of a continuous function over the closed interval $[0, a]$. So it exists. The fun part is evaluating it in closed form.